# Neural Networks Not Immediatelly Reproducible?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

With the random weight initializations in a feed-forward neural network using a derivative of backpropogation (resilient), the initial position on the error graph is atop some random valley which may or may not be a local minimum. It is possible to use methods to overcome local minimum, but assuming these are not used (or don't work well on the given terrain) it would seem that the neural network is not immediately reproducible. Meaning, there is a bit of luck involved.

On a graph with 1 Million valleys and only one global minimum, it would take a maximum of 1 Million Non-Repeating weight initializations to find that single global minimum (assuming each initialization landed you in a completely different valley). So, if I come across a convergence on a global minimum (the solution) and accidentally lose the weights (data corruption, or whatever), I may not come across the convergence again. With this in mind, should I be running a multitude of neural networks concurrently on the same data set and then halt/save the network once I reach my desired error rate?  I am aware that running multiple networks simultaneously is a common practice, but this would seem to make a semi-brute force technique like this mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Correct

You are indeed in dire need to store those calculated weights somewhere safe. You are not guaranteed  to rediscover the same (possibly) optimal solution again, given a difficult search landscape.

#### Multiple restarts

It is very common to use random restarts and keep track of the current best solution.

#### Litterature on learning in NN

See the great book extract: [A Systematic Introduction](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K8.pdf)

Comment: Thank you.  I have read that article and other portions from the larger work.  I really needed someone to spell it out for me, because I was not sure how much I should expect from adjusting the momentum and learning rate which is meant to help resolve these issues.  Also, some other forms of backprop, such as resilient do not utilize momentum or a learning rate but instead adjust the learning rate based on the last gradient, I think.  It seems there is no substitute for starting over.

Comment: Actually, in the worst case scenario using momentum would prevent you from reaching the global minimum by "jumping" back-and-fourth in the search space! The learning rate is recommended to be initialized to a low value, to avoid this problem - at the cost of slower learning (and potentially not being able to escape local optima). The resilient backpropagation is a better way to handle "difficult" search spaces. See this [backpropagation discussion](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christian_Igel/publication/2499275_Improving_the_Rprop_Learning_Algorithm/file/9c96052317c58a515c.pdf).