# Replicating results with different artificial neural network frameworks (ffnet, tensorflow)

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to model a technical process (a number of nonlinear equations) with artificial neural networks. The function has a number of inputs and a number of outputs (e.g. 50 inputs, 150 outputs - all floats).

I have tried the [python library ffnet](http://ffnet.sourceforge.net/overview.html) (wrapper for a fortran library) with great success. The errors for a certain dataset are well below 0.2%.

It is using a fully connected graph and these additional parameters.

```
Basic assumptions and limitations:
    Network has feed-forward architecture.
    Input units have identity activation function, all other units have sigmoid activation function.
    Provided data are automatically normalized, both input and output, with a linear mapping to the range (0.15, 0.85). Each input and output is treated separately (i.e. linear map is unique for each input and output).
    Function minimized during training is a sum of squared errors of each output for each training pattern.
```

I am using one input layer, one hidden layer (size: 2/3 of input vector + size of output vector) and an output layer. I'm using the scipy conjugate gradient optimizer.

The downside of ffnet is the long training time and the lack of functionality to use GPUs. Therefore i want to switch to a different framework and have chosen **keras with TensorFlow** as the backend.

I have tried to model the previous configuration:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, input_dim=n_in))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(n_hidden))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(n_out))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='Adamax',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However the results are far worse, the error is up to 0.5% with a few thousand (!) epochs of training. The ffnet training was automatically canceled at 292 epochs. Furthermore the differences between the network response and the validation target are not centered around 0, but mostly negative. 
I have tried all optimizers and different loss functions. I have also skipped the BatchNormalization and normalized the data manually in the same way that ffnet does it. Nothing helps.

**Does anyone have a suggestion to obtain better results with keras?**

Comment: Are you using the same optimization method? You seem to be using `Adamax` with `keras`.

Comment: keras does not include a conjugate gradient optimizer and Adamax has delivered the best results so far.

Comment: For such tiny dimensionality traditional NN optimizers like Adamax will work badly, with TensorFlow you could plug-in lBFGS optimizer using scipy interface -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/446

Comment: 'train_tnc' is generally faster and gives even better results with ffnet. With this method you can use nproc=n option which can speed up training on multicore machines (speedup is better with large networks and data sets).

Comment: I did use train_tnc with nproc=4, but it still was slightly slower than cg. I guess my problem size is too small? Anyway, i have reached very good results with keras now and can incorporate GPUs easily. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are trying to re-train the same architecture from scratch, with a different library. The first fundamental issue to keep in mind here is that neural nets [are not necessarily reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24161525/777285), when weights are initialized randomly.

For example, here is the default constructor parameter for `Dense` in Keras:

```
init='glorot_uniform'
```

But even before trying to evaluate the convergence of Keras optimizations, I would recommend trying to port the weights for which you got good results, from ffnet, into your Keras model. You can do so either with the *kwarg* `Dense(..., weights=`) of each layer, or globally at the end `model.set_weights(...)`

Using the same weights **must** yield the exact same result between the two libs. Unless you run into some floating point rounding issues. I believe that as long as porting the weights is not consistent, working on the optimization is unlikely to help.

Comment: Thank you. I ported the weight initialization from ffnet to keras and it had a tremendous effect.

Comment: Good to hear :) If it solved your problem, could you accept the answer ? Although the fact that the weight porting worked means that Keras optimization is not as good as ffnet's

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, but it was definitely a big factor, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: Although maybe you can help with a different problem which i'm having now: so one output value is always constant, regardless of input. unfortunately the neural net does not model that fact and generates a high regression (e.g. 0.4%) for that output whereas all other variable outputs are tracked within 0.1% or so.

Comment: is there a way to accurately make that output a constant except for leaving it out of the training output vector?

Comment: Well if you don't need to predict the value of one output value, I would definitely leave it out of the model. If nothing else, it adds unneeded complexity (CPU time)

Comment: As to why the neural net can't pick up the constant, I'm not sure. Without regularization, I would have thought the node could just blot out all input but the bias, and set the right weight for it, in order to output the constant.